# How to find the smallest number composed of only 1 that can divide by n, given n is a coprime of 10?

Tags: c++, math

I'm writing a program with which to find the smallest number **m** composed of only the number "1" that can divide by a given number **n**. **n** must be a co-prime of 10.

For example:

- n = 37 -> m = 111 (111/37 =3)
- n = 11 -> m = 1111 (1111/11 = 101)
- n = 91 -> m = 111111 (111111/91 = 1221)

My current code:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long int n, m = 1;
    cin>>n;
    while (m % n != 0) {
        m = m*10 + 1;
    }
    cout<<m;
}
```

I believe this is the right way to find m, but it runs into TLE **(Time Limit Exceeded)** problems, and I assume it's because:

- The code takes too many loops to find a number **m** that satisfies the conditions.
- There is no number **m** that satisfies the conditions.

Is there anyway to avoid TLE issues for this program? And is there anyway to mathematically find **m** based on **n**, or that number **m** does not exist?

I've found the solutions for Time Limit Exceeded error.

The solution was to reduce the steps in the while loop to:

```cpp
  while(m%n!=0)
{
        m=(m*10+1)%n;
        cout<<"1";
}
```

Despite this being solved, I am still curious about the way to find **m** mathematically (or to determine whether **m** exists), so any other inputs regarding this are appreciated.

Comment: Avoid overflowing when computing next `m`; for instance compare `m` with `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long int>::max() / 10 - 1` if you set `m`'s type is `unsigned long long int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the new version you found, you can be sure that there's no solution if the new `m` you computed was already encountered previously - that means you're on an infinite loop.

However, since caching previous values of `m` can be too much for the scope of this problem, you can resort to the weaker condition: if the loop run for more than `n` times - since `m` is always smaller than `n`, it means that at least one `m` value must have already repeated.

```c++
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned long int n = 12, m = 1;
    unsigned int count = 0;
    string result = "1";
    while(m%n!=0 && count < n){
        m=(m*10+1)%n;
        result = result + "1";
        count++;
    }
    cout << (m%n == 0 ? result : "no result") << endl;
}
```

The condition is weaker in the sense that you find out that there's no solution later, but the result is still correct.